# TradingView alerts are not being executed by strategy()

Tags: pine-script, alert, tradingview-api

In my Pine Script strategy function, I set the following parameters:

```
strategy("XXX", overlay=true,
         initial_capital = 1000, 
         default_qty_value = 50, 
         default_qty_type = "percent_of_equity",
         pyramiding = 4,
         commission_type = "percent",
         commission_value = 0.05,
         slippage = 0,
         process_orders_on_close = false,
         margin_long = 25,
         margin_short = 0, 
         calc_on_order_fills = true,
         calc_on_every_tick = false,
         use_bar_magnifier= true)
```

I set `calc_on_order_fills = true` and `calc_on_every_tick = false`. However, I noticed that TradingView alerts are being executed in real time as if `calc_on_every_tick = true`.

I expect TradingView alerts to be executed in real time as if `calc_on_order_fills = true` to avoid missing the optimal timing to trade.

Comment: What do you think `calc_on_order_fills` does?